# compare array, remove items

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Using the Google Places API, you can only get 20 results back from a single query ... so you can't query for ALL results at once, but rather need to store what has already been searched for (in an array) and add to that array or remove from that array...

This demonstrates my question ... I need to be able to add places to my array, but then search through the array and remove any places that are no longer needed.

Is there a "compare array" function that I should be utilizing, or perhaps something better? I just feel that's quite rudimentary... and perhaps I'm missing some Google API function that's obvious.

My plan is to create an object:

```
var placesObj = {};
```

And since all places can have multiple "types", I need to be able to push each place `id` into an array WITHIN the `placesObj` like so:

```
var placesObj = {
    bars: {'123123123123123', '123123123355555', '12312312132123'},
    parks: {'123123123123123', '123123123355555', '12312312132123'}
};
```

This way, I can look for the `id` string and remove it from the entire `placesObj` ...

I hope this makes sense... I just need to know how to construct this object.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php should be helpful for you.  It will return an array that has all the entries in array 1 that aren't present in the second array.  You should then be able to modify your arrays accordingly.

EDIT: Now that its clear that you're referencing javascript, not php, its a different conversation.  If I were going to compare JS objects and update them accordingly, I'd use key value pairs and delete like so:

```
var placesObj = {
    bars: {'tavern': '123123123123123', 'bar123':'123123123355555', 'blahblah':'12312312132123'},
    parks: {'jungle' : '123123123123123', 'kidspar;':'123123123355555', 'foo': '12312312132123'}
}; 

delete placesObj['tavern']; 
delete placesObj['yourKey'];
```

I'm assuming you're getting json responses from google and building this object from the response...you could probably just use some other unique value that you're getting from google to make the key like the place's name.

Comment: Yes, but lets say that you uncheck an option for `bars` ... but will then need to remove all bar markers only.

Comment: It depends on how you've structured your data.  Can you add a code sample so we can ensure we're discussing something concrete?

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your effort ... but I need to rethink this. I don't know how I'm supposed to remove only the markers that are no longer needed.